# I have a problem building my app through an ios simulator using android studio. The error is

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm a total beginner and am learning flutter with the help of youtube videos. At first I can still build and run my codes normally but after some time an error comes up when I run it. Can anyone help me? I've searched and google everywhere but still no solution comes up.

[build code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNzhH.png)

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buY0u.png)

Comment: Android Studio and iOS simulator? That doesn't go together.

Comment: Im sorry maybe you could clarify your comment because i run the iOS simulator connected to Android Studio all the time

Comment: Have you tried deleting your podfile I can post steps if needed? Also have you been editing files in the iOS folder?

Comment: when i try to build with an ios simulator the error comes up but it works normally with an android simulator. what is a podfile and how do i delete it? @wcyankees424

Comment: ill post the steps given me couple minutes in the mean time run flutter clean in the terminal of your project just to make sure that doesn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your error closer I believe this is your problem. Your Error:  Xcode - resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed. According to what I can determine can be fixed like this.

**Solution** 
Open terminal and execute this command where project_dir would be your flutter project

```
 xattr -cr <path_to_project_dir>
```

**Or**
Navigate to your projects root directory from within your terminal then execute this command

```
xattr -cr .
```